# POSTMAN Sign in to your account for MS AZURE protected webAPIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman

I have an application with APIs which uses MS Azure based authentication. In browser I can run the get APIs and see the result. I am trying to setup Postman for this application. Since it has authentication in place, I had followed few articles to do the setup.

Until now what I had tried is setting up an environment in postman with below variables:

```
callbackUrl: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
clientId
tenantId
clientSecret
scope: api://clientid/.default}
productApiUrl
```

After this I set the Authorization to OAuth 2.0 and configured a new token. The new token got created and it prompted authentication completed. With this setting I am running my Get API, this gives me an HTML response with Sign in to your account.

I am not sure why I am getting HTML response to Sign In because this prompt never comes in browser.

I am not able to debug this, any help on how can I debug/resolve this.

To generate token, I am using these values
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please mention the grant_type you are using to generate the token?

Comment: It is Authorization code  @MRRukmini

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/869787/msal-azure-protected-web-api-giving-error-34sign-i.html

Comment: In this post it is mentioned that "In the postman, we are testing API without calling client application by providing access token authenticated using your client application details as shown below, then you need to provide URL specific of protected API rather than URL of client application." What is "URL specific of protected API" and where to provide this?

Comment: That error is same as discussed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/869787/msal-azure-protected-web-api-giving-error-34sign-i.html but we don't have any browser pop up in our application to ask for authentication